# Gulp.js event stream merge order

Tags: javascript, concatenation, gulp, event-stream, gulp-sass

I am trying to merge css and scss files into a main.css file that goes in my build directory.
Its working, but not in the right order. The style attributes from the scss files need to be in the bottom of the main.css file so they overrule the rest.

my Gulp task looks like this:

```
    //CSS
gulp.task('css', function () {
    var cssTomincss = gulp.src(['dev/css/reset.css', 'dev/css/style.css','dev/css/typography.css',    'dev/css/sizes.css']);

    var cssFromscss = gulp.src(['dev/css/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass());

    return es.merge(cssTomincss, cssFromscss)
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
});
```

I am defining the sources first with variables. I am using the gulp-sass plugin to convert the scss file into normal css (.pipe(sass)) and later merging the two with the es.merge function and concatenating them into main.css.

The problem is that the style attributes van the .scss files end up somewhere in the top end of the main.css file. I need them to be at the bottom. So they need to be concatenated at the bottom.

Any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try [streamqueue](https://www.npmjs.org/package/streamqueue).

```
var streamqueue = require('streamqueue');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
            gulp.src(['dev/css/reset.css', 'dev/css/style.css', 'dev/css/typography.css', 'dev/css/sizes.css']),
            gulp.src(['dev/css/*.scss']).pipe(sass())
        )
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
});
```

[This cheatsheet](https://github.com/osscafe/gulp-cheatsheet) will help you. [PDF](https://github.com/osscafe/gulp-cheetsheet/raw/master/dist/en-js-p2.pdf) is here.

Comment: Ok, that was epic. It worked! Looked into it and I understand it now. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Hi! I'm using streamqueue thanks to you.. but running into issues :( mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522916/how-to-order-the-compiling-of-javascript-files-in-gulp

Comment: streamqueue always throws "Cannot switch to old mode now". Using merge-stream and then gulp-order works though.

Comment: It doesn't concat them in the right order :(  Even if I invert the order in streamqueue, it still outputs the same (wrong) way. How does that even... ?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the plugin **[gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order)** fits perfectly well in your case.

It allows you to re-order the passed `stream` with your own `glob` pattern, for example based on your code :

```
return es.merge(cssTomincss, cssFromscss)
    .pipe(order([
      'dev/css/reset.css',
      'dev/css/style.css',
      'dev/css/typography.css',
      'dev/css/sizes.css',
      'dev/css/*.css',
    ]))
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
```

One drawback of this is that you have to re-declare your `globs`, but you can get around by assign your `globs` to a value and then concat them in you `order` pipe, much cleaner.

You may have to set the `base` option to `.` of *gulp-order* as stated in their Readme if the files were not ordered correctly.

One another way would be to use **[stream-series](https://github.com/rschmukler/stream-series)**, basically the same as *event-stream*, but the order of your stream is preserved, and you don't have to rewrite your `globs`.

Comment: sometimes it didn't pickup paths as expected. Using `.pipe(order[path1, path2], { base: '.' })` solved it.

Comment: Hum, were the files in different folders? Will add this info in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Great answer - just a reminder to people following this answer that you need to install gulp-order via npm and import it at the top of your gulp file.

Answer (score 5):

I tried **[gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order)** without success: the order somehow wasn't taken into account.

The solution which worked for me was using **[stream-series](https://github.com/rschmukler/stream-series)**, mentioned by [Aperçu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054072/aper%c3%a7u).

```
return streamSeries(
    cssTomincss,
    cssFromscss)
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I failed with all provided answers, they produced some silent errors. Finally [merge2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2) worked for me (seems like there was `gulp-merge` and later the project was renamed into `merge2`). I'm not sure why there is a need in [streamify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamify) plugin, e.g. streams created with Rollup may produce "stream-not-supported-errors" with `gulp-concat`, `gulp-uglify` or `gulp-insert`.

```
const mergeStreams = require('merge2');
const streamify = require('streamify');
...
gulp.task('build', () => {
    const streams = sources.map(createJSFile);
    return mergeStreams(...streams)
        .pipe(streamify(concat('bundle.js')))
        .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```