# Gulp pipe and caching issue when using "gulp-translate-html" and "gulp-inject"

Tags: javascript, json, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-inject

I have a project where I have to generate translated static pages.
The choice was to use gulp because it helps a lot in minifying resources, watch for file changes and re-compile, and can also inject html templates in several pages.

I used:
 
 - 'gulp-inject': for inserting templates into final files 
 
 - 'gulp-translate-html': for translating because I have '.json' dictionaries

So I have two issues:

1. 'gulp-translate-html'

This uses the json as input for translating, using the following code:

```
 gulp.task('translate', function() {
            return gulp.src('./temp/en/template.html')
                .pipe(translateHtml({
                    messages: require('./dictionary/en.json'),
                    templateSettings: {
                        interpolate: /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g
                    }       
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./en'));
    });
```

I created a watch on the '.json' file, when modified, it should re-apply the translation. But somehow it uses the old file instead of the modified one.
Is there a workaround for this? Or other plugin that I could use for the json files?

2. 'gulp-inject'
   In the code-sample above, I translated only one file. But I need to do so for several languages that have different destinations, so I used a loop for the languages.(sorry for the code indentation)

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp'),
           inject = require('gulp-inject'),
           translateHtml = require('gulp-translate-html');
   var languages = ['en', 'de'];

   gulp.task('injectContent', function() {
           /* the base file used as a reference*/
           var target = gulp.src('./templates/base/baseTemplate.html'); 
           /* get each language*/
            languages.forEach(function(lang) {
               target.pipe(inject(gulp.src('./templates/partials/injectTemplate.html'), {
                   relative: true,
                   starttag: '<!-- inject:template -->',
                   transform: function (filePath, file) {
                       return file.contents.toString('utf8');
                   }
               }))
               /* put the merged files into "temp" folder under its language folder*/
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp/'+lang)); 
            });
    });

   /* The translation has to be made after the injection above is finished*/
   gulp.task('translate', ['injectContent'] function() {
   /* get each language*/
   languages.forEach(function(lang) { 
       gulp.src('./temp/'+ lang +'/baseTemplate.html')
           .pipe(translateHtml({
               messages: require('./dictionary/'+lang+'.json');,
               templateSettings: {
                   interpolate: /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g
               }       
           }))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./'+lang)); /* put file in the "en" or "de" language folder*/
    });
   });

   gulp.task('watch', function() {
           gulp.watch(['./templates/**/*.html', './dictionary/*.json'], ['translate']);
   });

   gulp.task('default', ['translate', 'watch']);
   ```

Here I want the 'injectContent' task to be ran before the 'translation' task, but the latter runs too soon. This happens because there is not a specific return gulp callback in the 'injectContent', right?

How can I merge the results and not let the tasks intercalate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution for the caching issue from point 1:

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060619/944637 I deleted the cache and then the "require" function could reload the file from the filesystem and not from cache.

I added `delete require.cache[require.resolve('./dictionary/en.json')];` at the beginning of the 'translate' task, before return.

EDIT: Just found the solution on Point 2 to merge the results using "merge-stream", in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26786529

so my code turned out to be like this:

```
   ....
    merge = require('merge-stream');
    gulp.task('injectContent', function() {
            var tasks = languages.map(function(lang){
                return gulp.src('./templates/base/injectContent.html')
                .pipe(plumber())
                .pipe(debug())
                .pipe(inject(gulp.src('./templates/partials/injectTemplate.html'), {
                    relative: true,
                    starttag: '<!-- inject:release -->',
                    transform: function (filePath, file) {
                        return file.contents.toString('utf8');
                    }
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp/'+lang));
            });
        return merge(tasks);
    });

    gulp.task('translate', ['injectContent'], function() {

        for (var i in languages) {
            var lang = languages[i];

            delete require.cache[require.resolve('./dictionary/'+lang+'.json')];

            gulp.src('./temp/'+lang+'/injectContent.html')
                .pipe(plumber())
                .pipe(debug())
                .pipe(translateHtml({
                    messages: require('./dictionary/'+lang+'.json'),
                    templateSettings: {
                        interpolate: /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g // this is for Angular-like variable syntax
                    }       
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./'+lang));
        }
    });
....
```