# Gulp-sass with different paths

Tags: symfony, gulp, gulp-sass

I have this project in Symfony

```
src
  ProjectName
    AdminBundle
      Resources
        public
          css
            style1.css
            style2.ccs
        sass
          style1.scss
          style2.scss
    AdvertiserBundler
      ..
    CommonBundle
      ..
    PublicBundle
      ..
    WebmaserBundle
      ..
```

All bundles have the same structure. All `*.scss` files are in `Resources/sass/` and compiled `*.css` files are in `Resources/public/css/`. How I can put all files from A to B *with one function*? I try work with `base`, but nothing happens.

This is `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css')
;

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('src/ProjectName/*Bundle/Resources/sass/*.scss', {
        base: 'sass'
    })
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 5 version', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'))
    ;
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles'], function() {    
    gulp.watch('src/ProjectName/*Bundle/Resources/sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

I don't want write like this five times:

```
....
gulp.src('src/ProjectName/AdminBundle/Resources/sass/*.scss')
.pipe(gulp.dest('src/ProjectName/AdminBundle/Resources/public/css'))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple paths as follows: `gulp.src(['path1', 'path2'])`.
Source: [Glob stream](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-stream)

Comment: How can I write this for compile css in gulp.dest? For `/public/css/`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784094/can-i-use-a-gulp-task-with-multiple-sources-and-multiple-destinations) might be worth the read =)