# Using gulp-jscs for multiple sources with multiple destinations

Tags: gulp, gulp-jscs

Assuming my structure looks like this:

```
 - app.js            
 - .jscsrc
 - gulpfile.babel.js                                                                                                                                                                          
 \ - clientside                                                                                                                                                                                
   \ - client1.js                                                                                                                                                                              
   \ - client2.js                                                                                                                                                                              
   \ - lib                                                                                                                                                                                   
     \ - serval libs...                                                                                                                                                                      
 \ - serverside                                                                                                                                                                                
   \ - server1.js                                                                                                                                                                              
   \ - server2.js                                                                                                                                                                              
   \ - lib                                                                                                                                                                                   
     \ - serval libs...
```

How can you `jscs` every file in the project, and overwrite the file with the result, while excluding the *lib* folders?

The only way I figured out is to write several gulp tasks for every folder (client-, serverside), and for every file that is not in a folder (app.js, gulpfile.babel.js) making my already long gulp file even longer.
Is there any short approach?

Comment: Just to point it out, this should not be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784094/can-i-use-a-gulp-task-with-multiple-sources-and-multiple-destinations since they actually want to merge the output into one file.