# gulp task for(... in ...) create correctly?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-load-plugins

What am I doing wrong?

**gulpfile.js**

```js
'use strict';

// Modules & Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
const image = require('gulp-image');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

let directories = [
  '2006/Art1',
  '2006/Art2',
  '2010/Art1'
];

function gulpTask(directoryName) {
  gulp.task('blogmotionAllMedia', function () {
    return gulp
      .src('src/content/' + directoryName + '/media/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}')
      .pipe($.responsive({
        '*.jpg': [
          { width: 400, rename: { suffix: '-4' } },
          { rename: { suffix: '-6' } }
        ],
      }))
      .pipe(image({
        jpegRecompress: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/content/' + directoryName + '/media'))
  });
}

var directory;

for (directory in directories) {
  gulpTask(directory);
}
```

*run task*
`npx gulp gulpTask`

**unexpected**

*I get the following error message:*

`Task never defined: gulpTask`

I am still attached to my [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193324/automatically-declare-the-variable-each-time-it-is-run/62194245#62194245) with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194245/9050912) (idea) from [Miles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4075712/miles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the gulp task should be registered with the name you want to invoke it `gulp.task('blogmotionAllMedia', ...` should be `gulp.task('gulpTask', ...`.
Furthermore I think you should iterate over the directories inside of the task.

Additionally I think you need to merge the resulting streams using [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) by `const merge = require('merge-stream')` and `return merge(directories.map(singleDirectoryGulpTask));`

Result should look like this:
(Disclaimer: haven't done gulp stuff for years. Still hope it helps)

```
'use strict';

// Modules & Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
const image = require('gulp-image');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
const merge = require('merge-stream')

let directories = [
    '2006/Art1',
    '2006/Art2',
    '2010/Art1'
];

gulp.task('gulpTask', function () {
    function singleDirectoryGulpTask(directoryName) {
        return gulp
            .src('src/content/' + directoryName + '/media/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}')
            .pipe($.responsive({
                '*.jpg': [
                    { width: 400, rename: { suffix: '-4' } },
                    { rename: { suffix: '-6' } }
                ],
            }))
            .pipe(image({
                jpegRecompress: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/content/' + directoryName + '/media'));
    }

    return merge(directories.map(singleDirectoryGulpTask));
});
```

Comment: thanks, i did try it and got this message: The following tasks did not complete: gulpTask
Did you forget to signal async completion? what that means?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784094/can-i-use-a-gulp-task-with-multiple-sources-and-multiple-destinations you need to use `merge-stream` to collect the resulting streams of multiple gulp calls.

Comment: danke für Deine Hilfe! Liebe Grüße aus Wien! {thank you for your help! Greetings from Vienna!}

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (directory in directories) {
  gulpTask(directory);
}
```

to:

```
for (directory of directories) {
  gulpTask(directory);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. takes only the first pictures from the first directory