# How to order the compiling of javascript files in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

Hi I'm trying to fix the order of the js files that get compiled in my Gulp task.

The order I need:

```
'/_sources/js/libs/*.js'
'/_sources/js/plugins/*.js'
'/_sources/js/custom/*.js'
'/_components/*.js'
```

Issue is that the custom folder contains a **custom particlesJS** script and the **main particlesJS** script is inside the plugins folder. So if the **custom script** ends up above the **main particlesJS** in the compiled js file everything breaks.

I tried to re-order things with **[gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order)** and `event-stream` but the .order doesn't seem to work, still compiles in the wrong order:

```
function compile_js(minify, folder) {
    var jsLibs = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/libs/*.js');
    var jsPlugins = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/plugins/*.js');
    var jsCustom = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/custom/*.js');
    var jsComponents = gulp.src(folder+'/_components/*.js');

    return es.merge(jsLibs, jsPlugins, jsComponents, jsCustom)
        .pipe(order([
            folder+'/_sources/js/libs/*.js',
            folder+'/_sources/js/plugins/*.js',
            folder+'/_sources/js/custom/*.js',
            folder+'/_components/*.js'
        ]))
        .pipe(concat('bitage_scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(minify, uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder+'/_assets/js'));
};
```

Next I tried **[streamqueue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamqueue)**:

```
function compile_js(minify, folder) {
    var jsLibs = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/libs/*.js');
    var jsPlugins = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/plugins/*.js');
    var jsCustom = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/custom/*.js');
    var jsComponents = gulp.src(folder+'/_components/*.js');

    return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
        gulp.src([
            jsLibs,
            jsPlugins,
            jsCustom]),
        gulp.src([jsComponents]).pipe(sass())
    )
    .pipe(concat('bitage_scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(minify, uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folder+'/_assets/js'));
};
```

Which threw this error: `Error: Invalid glob argument: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

**The task:**

```
// Development task
gulp.task('devsite', function () {
    minify = false;
    return compile_js(minify, 'public');
});
```

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
function compile_js(minify, folder) {
  var jsLibs = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/libs/*.js');
  var jsPlugins = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/plugins/*.js');
  var jsCustom = gulp.src(folder+'/_sources/js/custom/*.js');
  var jsComponents = gulp.src(folder+'/_components/*.js');

  return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
    jsLibs,
    jsPlugins,
    jsCustom,
    jsComponents
  )
  .pipe(concat('bitage_scripts.js'))
  .pipe(gulpif(minify, uglify()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(folder+'/_assets/js'));
};
```

`gulp.src(gulp.src('folder+'/_source/something'))` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmm just tried that, still getting the glob error and when I remove `gulp.src(` I get an Arguments to path.join must be strings :(

Comment: Oh btw I removed  `.pipe(sass())` it's js not css

Comment: OH! Ok so removing the `sass()` fixed it! :D checking your answer, but you should remove the `sass` part...